# How to fix int rounding when drawing tiles on a board using Swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently trying to make the Puzzle-15 in java.

I use a list of BufferedImage as the tiles and use g2d to paint them at coordinates (x,y). 
I calculate how big each tile should be by:

```
int borderSize = 4;
int boardSize = 400 - 4*2;
int tilesPerRow = 40;
int tileSize = boardSize/tilesPerRow; // This will be floored to 9.
```

Then when the image is painted it only paints tiles 9*40. 360 pixels.. So there are 32 pixels left over. You can clearly see how ugly that is if you look at the image i've added down below.

I've tried to use affineTransform, but i can't make it work.

I hope one of you have a great idea:)

[image]

Comment: how many tiles do you want per row? if you paint 40 it will paint 40; you want some of them 10 pixels and some of them 9 so that total is 392? how many tiles in total do you want?

Comment: any way I dont undrstand you final goal; it seems yu leave also a 32 pixel empty at the top; how do you want it? please explain

Comment: I want the tiles to fill the 392 pixels.
I know that i can do it by adding 1px to some of them, but then when i make the animation it's very difficult the way i've done it.

I'd love if i could somehow draw sub pixels or if there is another way?

Comment: You aren't going to be able to evenly fill up your space with equal sized tiles, but couldn't you increase the size of your box to 408x408, so that you have an even 400x400 space for your tiles and you could just use 10 pixel tiles?

Comment: I might be able too.. But then it will have to resize all the time. It should be able to take all amounts of tiles from 3..100 :s

Answer (score 0):

Heres my two approaches:

if you want x1 to be 10 and x2 to be 9 for a total of 392

you have 10*x1+9*x2=392

x1+x2=40

you solve the equations and get x1 and x2

B:

you magnify the space to 3920 and have 98 pixels per tile: 40*98

then you rescale down to 392 - it's a uniform scaling by 10 and the scaling is up to the graphics system

Comment: I like this way! Thanks. I'll try and see if it can work and if it won't be too heavy on the graphics.